# Can't download Accord NuGet in VS 2015 nor VS 2017

Tags: visual-studio, ffmpeg, uwp, trie, accord.net

Here is the package,,, NuGet Accord.Video.FFMPEG

Here is the error,,,
Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'EssentialTimeLapseVideo'.

I used this NuGet in a Windows Form app I am working on, and had no issues.  Then something came up with Time Lapse, and I wanted to use it in a UWP, but, for some reason it won't install.

I tried the mirror suggested, and got the following.
[image]

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks, John.

Comment: You can use other mirror nuget like https://nuget.cnblogs.com/v3/index.json

Comment: I tried it, got a different error,

Comment: It looks like this package is simply incompatible with `UWP`. My VS **Output** window shows this: _**Package Accord.Video 3.5.0 is not compatible with uap10.0.10586 (UAP,Version=v10.0.10586).**_

Comment: That's what I was thinking.  No worries though, I got the rendering done with some Microsoft libraries.  Thanks for looking into this.

Answer (score 1):

jstreet has the answer in his comment.  Apparently the library is not compatible with UWP.  Thanks for your help!  John.